# How to hide an active app from Dock on MacBook

Tags: macos, mac

Trying this with TeamViewer and I cant seem to make it work.

The first method I tried was by text editing.I opened package contents and tried to edit the `info.plist` file. It didn't allow me permission to edit the file so I duplicated it and pasted it back into package contents (which replaced the info.plst file).  This is the line that I inserted into the file:

[image]

I then tried opening the app but the icon briefly appears in the dock then disappears. I can't use the app.

I also tried to do by inserting a line on terminal but maybe im not using terminal correctly but I couldn't get this to work either. This is the line I've found on the Internet (I changed 'AppName' to Teamviewer):

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Add :LSUIElement bool true' /Applications/[AppName].app/Contents/Info.plist
```

I also tried an app called Ghostile which is similar to Dock Dodger, which doesn't exist anymore but it says it doesn't support the app. Any advice or help?

Comment: Can you please past the actual `PlistBuddy` command you've used?

Comment: Hi , I added this

Comment: You added a screenshot which shows hardly anything. Please copy/paste the full file, and also the command you tried with the second step

Comment: I really hope you can't do that if someone is using team viewer on my machine I want it to show uo so I can make sure it is closed when we have finished  usingbut

Comment: You are supposed to use the real application name, not [AppName] :-)

Comment: BTW changing **any** file inside an application's package (I *believe*) will change the checksum of the package and break the signature of that app causing it to not run. Which explains why the app you modified won't run. You'll have to restore that from a backup. (All you programmers please pardon or correct my attempt to explain what I, at best, only vaguely understand.)